# Async/Await on Axios

Tags: javascript

So this is not a technical problem, but more the fundamental question.

```js
async getBestServer() {
      await axios
        .get("https://api.gofile.io/getServer")
        .then((response) => {
          (this.server = response.data.data.server);
          console.log("on axios = " + this.server);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
      console.log("on data = " + this.server);
    },
```

I tried to get a request on this go file api (its public so its ok), then i wanna store it on my data object, what i confuse here is what is actually async/await does in this function? what i know is await will wait for axios to settle the response to the data, then run the second console log below, but what if i dont use await, why the javascript cant wait for axios to settle the data first? i mean isnt that how synchronus works right?

I appreciate if you give me a simple explanation, not just answer with redirect to an article because I've read lot of them but still confuse with this function I made.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `async`/`await` pattern is a much-readable yet error-proof alternative to the then/catch you've used.

Basically, instead of writing:

```
getBestServer() {
  axios
    .get("https://api.gofile.io/getServer")
    .then((response) => {
      (this.server = response.data.data.server);
      console.log("on axios = " + this.server);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  console.log("on data = " + this.server);
}
```

You can do the same thing with `async`/`await`, but in a imperative-like way:

```
async getBestServer() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://api.gofile.io/getServer");
    this.server = response.data.data.server;
    console.log("on axios = " + this.server);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

As you can see, in the first snippet the last `console.log` will be executed immediately as the `get` is raised. However, since the HTTP request would take a while (respect to the script execution), it becomes confusing to "wait" until the actual data has been received.

In the second snippet, the magic-`await` does this "wait" for you. Much easier to maintain, much easier to understand what the code does, yet way less error due to dirty code.

The clarity of the difference becomes even greater if you need to cascade two or three calls.

The old-fashion code would look like:

```
getBestServer() {
  axios
    .get("https://api.gofile.io/getServer")
    .then((response1) => {
      (this.server = response1.data.data.server);
      console.log("on axios = " + this.server);
      
      axios.get("https://another-service")
        .then(response2 => {
          console.log("second call served...")
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

Pretty messy, isn't it?

However, you can take advantage of `async`/`await`, so that would become:

```
async getBestServer() {
  try {
    const response1 = await axios.get("https://api.gofile.io/getServer");
    this.server = response.data.data.server;
    console.log("on axios = " + this.server);

    const response2 = await axios.get("https://another-service");
    console.log("second call served...")
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Bonus: a single error catch without any effort!

Comment: Nice explained. Now I understand the concept, thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is asynchronous single threaded, whenever you send request to server, it has to wait, first to get to server and then to get answer from server, and making that single thread to wait will pause whole process. So in order to minimize wasted time on waiting, Javascript moves to do other things before response gets back. But there will be situations where you need to wait for something, in that situation by marking api call with await Javascript knows that first it needs to wait for response and then move to next step in that function.